# Remove codebase between two git tags

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a situation, where

1. I have a tag v.0
2. written some new code and push into master.
3. created a tag v.1.
4. written some new code and push into master.
5. created a new tag v.2

Now if I want to remove code written between v.0 and v.1 and I also want to remove tag v.1
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This requires you to "rewrite history", which is generally considered a bad idea if your repository is public.  But essentially you need to make all of these changes locally and then force push your local changes to origin.  I believe this would look like:

```
git rebase -i v.0
# delete the desired range of commits by deleting lines in the `git-rebase-todo` file that is presented
git tag --delete v.1
git push --force-with-lease
```